# Concurrent counters on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, transactions, counter

The current setup I have is a InnoDB table which holds the counters I need on my application. Each row is identified by a key and has a counter value (last value used).

This is being used by a PHP Application, which needs unique identifiers for different entities. There must be no duplication on the numbers and this can't be done with constraints on the end column as the counter itself is resettable.

The number is not always retrieved in the end of the transaction and using either select for update or even update and select, the resource will be locked until the transaction is committed. Some transactions are quite heavy (refactor is not an option at this point of time) and they're creating lock wait timeout to reach this resource.

What would be the best solution for implementing this counter, using MySQL only.

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution for a while before moved my counters to Redis.

```
UPDATE `counters` SET `children_count` = (SELECT (@a:= `children_count` + 1))
WHERE `node_id` = 1'
```

Then you get the value with

```
SELECT @a AS `children_count`
```

The value is availavale in current session.